# Mathematical definition of a hedge?

Tags: portfolio-management, finance-mathematics, hedging, terminology

For two given portfolios/trading strategies I want to know what criteria need to fulfilled in order to call the one portfolio a hedge to the other. In other words; **what is the *mathematical* definition of a hedge given in terms of the value processes of the portfolios?** before down voting this question for being to *basic* please google ‘hedge definition’ and the first many hits won’t give you an mathematical definition but rather oral explanations. Thanks

Comment: It sure seems like everyone wants to define hedging by examples and oral explanations. There must be some quant who has given a mathematical definition

Comment: This should and will get voted down though. Please google “mathematics of hedging”.

Comment: I agree that the question is "too" basic yet the author is right when he/she claims that it's actually not easy to find through what the mathematical definition is. I had to look it up in a book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a T-claim $X$, then $h$ is a hedge portfolio if and only if $h$ is self-financing and the value $V^h(t)$ at time $T$ is as following: $$V^h(T)=X$$

Comment: I assume you know what  the terms T-claim and self-financing means.

Comment: I would like to add that hedges are model-dependent.    For example, the amount of stock needed to hedge a call option is dependent on your theory of how to value the call option (Black Scholes,  Heston, etc).